# (google sheets or excel) How can I find the closest matching value above the current cell, and return a different column in that same row?

Tags: google-sheets, lookup

I asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69948860/how-can-i-find-the-closest-matching-value-above-the-current-cell-and-return-a-d), but I've hit another roadblock. I've included a visual below of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: example of ideal results]

For any row where Column A=x, just return the value in Column B to Column "Results". If Column A does not equal x, I want to return the closest (in distance) Column B value above the current row where Column A=x and Column B is any 3 digit number. The first part (where Column A=x) is simple, but I'm having trouble with the second part, where Column A <> x. In the linked question, I was able to use the solution to find the closest value above the current cell where Column A=x, but I have not been able to figure out how to find the closest value above the current cell where Column A=x AND Column B is any 3 digit number. Any suggestions would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please note, there is no guarantee that a solution in Google Sheets will work in Excel, or vice versa.

Comment: Of course- I have access to google sheets and excel, so I am happy to use either one!

Comment: did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69949447/5632629

Comment: @player0- yes! using that solution I can get the nearest column B value where Column A=x, but I'm struggling to add the second condition, where column b is any 3 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(B:B="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(B:B), 
 IF(ISNUMBER(1*B:B)*(LEN(B:B)=3), {ROW(B:B), B:B}), 2, 1)))
```

`ISNUMBER` will check for the digits and `LEN` will check for 3 numbers